# Seeing part of a clip before it fully downloaded

Tags: download, media, flv

Is there any way to see the part that been downloded of a clip (wmv, flv..etc) from any download site like mediafire.. I mean to see the clip before it fully downloaded.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @Adam543i: i'm using firefox

Comment: I believe that Firefox names downloading files <name>.part so try opening that with a video viewer.